# establish the identity $\|u+v\|^2+\|u-v\|^2=2\|u\|^2+2\|v\|^2$ for $u$, $v \in \mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

establish the identity $\|u+v\|^2+\|u-v\|^2=2\|u\|^2+2\|v\|^2$ for $u$, $v \in \mathbb R^n$.

I couldn't understand how to solve it  please just give me the first step, maybe I can figure out the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the fact that $\|a\|^2 = a \bullet a$ ($a$ dot product itself).

Then $\|u+v\|^2 = (u+v)\bullet (u+v) = u\bullet (u+v) + v \bullet (u+v) = u\bullet u+ u\bullet v + v\bullet u + v\bullet v$.

You can expand $\|u-v\|^2$ in the same way.

The identity should follow pretty easily! :)

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it's just hard to know where to start. :)

Answer (score 1):

Turn all those norms into inner (dot products), using $\|u\|^2=u\cdot u$. Appeal to properties of inner (dot) products.